# Install php7.0 mongodb on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 64 bit

I am trying to install mongodb driver for php7.0

There is no driver for this version.

How can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not, there is driver for it, to install use

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

do not sepcify any version on the `php`, like `php7`.  just `php-mongodb`

You can do a manual install via the pecl extension using

```
$ sudo pecl install mongodb
```

for further info, check out [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765146/how-to-install-mongodb-php-extension-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)